# Package for tickmark / cross comparison

Tags: packages

I am looking for a package I saw in a presentation one time.

Sorry I can't succinctly describe the package I am looking for, but that is why I cannot find it on a search engine. I want to create a picture to describe a comparison between two things. There are two columns, one for each compared thing (for example chickens and humans), and then as many rows as comparisons we have (for example 'want to live', 'can suffer', 'socially acceptable to gas chamber'). There is then a green checkmark in the column if it satisfies the condition, and a red cross otherwise. In this case it would be something like

```
                 chicken human

live             v       v

suffer           v       v

gas chamber      v       x
```

What is this package called / is there something else I can use to make this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `dingbat` package has a `\checkmark`  command and `bbding` has  `\XSolidBold` and `\XSolidBrush`.